# How to persist email and password textfield info using UserDefaults if checkbox is selected Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I'm using BEMCheckBox library for checkbox.
The thing is when checkbox is true it doesn't save the inputs from the users

What I tried to do is when checkbox == true
it should,
save email and password and and set checkbox to true, then save it to user default.

if == false
should delete everything (email, password and reset checkbox to false).
, but it's not working.

```
 var Defaults = UserDefaults.standard

@IBOutlet weak var box1: BEMCheckBox!

 struct keys {

    static let emailKey = "emailTextField"
    static let passwordKey = "passwordTextField"
    static var boxBool = "boxBool"

}
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    didTap(box1)
    box1.delegate = self
    checkSavedData()
}


func didTap(_ checkBox: BEMCheckBox) {


    if checkBox.on == true {

        rememberMyEmailandPassword()

    } else if checkBox.on == false {

        Defaults.removeObject(forKey: keys.emailKey)
        Defaults.removeObject(forKey: keys.passwordKey)
        Defaults.removeObject(forKey: keys.boxBool)
    }

}

 func rememberMyEmailandPassword() {
    Defaults.set(emailTextField.text, forKey: keys.emailKey)
    Defaults.set(passwordTextField.text, forKey: keys.passwordKey)
    Defaults.set(box1.on, forKey: keys.boxBool)


}

func checkSavedData() {
    let email = Defaults.value(forKey: keys.emailKey) as? String ?? ""
    let password = Defaults.value(forKey: keys.passwordKey) as? String ?? ""
    let boxBoolean = Defaults.bool(forKey: keys.boxBool)

    emailTextField.text = email
    passwordTextField.text = password
    box1.on = boxBoolean
}
```

I think the problem with boxBoolean. because I believe boxBoolean doesn't recall the data again.

Thnx.

Comment: `boxBoolean` only affects the single boolean inside `UserDefaults`. Why would this have anything to d with the rest of the data?? Also, for naming convention standards, I'd do `var default = UserDefaults.standard`

Comment: @impression7vx `default` is reserved. Better to use `defaults` and declare it as constant.

Comment: @impression7vx do you mean the purpose of boxBoolean ? and why I need it ?

Comment: @Nawaf `== true` is redundant and `if checkBox.on == false` can be just omitted. `if checkBox.on  {

        rememberMyEmailandPassword()

    } else { ... }`

Comment: Don't use `value(forKey)`. It is for KVO. You should use `UserDefaults` specific method for retrieving  String values called `string(forKey:)`. `let email = defaults.string(forKey: Keys.emailKey) ?? ""` Btw you should name your structures starting with an uppercase letter. It would be better to use an enumeration instead.

Comment: And don't forget to unwrap your values `emailTextField.text!` and `passwordTextField.text!`

Comment: And only call `checkSavedData()` in viewDidLoad  `if checkBox.on`

Comment: Another issue it only saves when you tap the check box. You should save the values when  editing changes on any field

Comment: @LeoDabus thnx for your help and also the other guys. I'm trying to make my code cleaner based on your comments.Moreover, when I remove defaults.removeObject. the app can retrieve email and password but I cannot delete the data when  I turn the checkbox to false.

Comment: @Nawaf I will post a code snippet. It might have some syntax errors but you will understand what was wrong with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var defaults = UserDefaults.standard

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var box1: BEMCheckBox!

enum Keys: String {
    case email, password, box1
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    // 1) loads the checkBox state when the view loads
    box1.on = defaults.bool(forKey: Keys.box1.rawValue)

    box1.delegate = self

    // 2) update the UI in case it is checked
    if box1.on { 
       loadData() 
    }
    // 3) adds a control event for editing changed to both fields
    emailTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(saveData), for: .editingChanged)
    passwordTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(saveData), for: .editingChanged)
}

func didTap(_ checkBox: BEMCheckBox) {

    // 4) saves the checkbox state
    defaults.set(box1.on, forKey: Keys.box1.rawValue)

    // 5) Saves field data or remove it
    if box1.on  {
        defaults.set(emailTextField.text!, forKey: Keys.email.rawValue)
        defaults.set(passwordTextField.text!, forKey: Keys.password.rawValue)
    } else {
        // 6) You should NEVER remove the checkbox value
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: Keys.email.rawValue)
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: Keys.password.rawValue)
    }
}

@objc func saveData(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // 7) update the data as the user types it in case it is checked
    if box1.on  {
        defaults.set(emailTextField.text!, forKey: Keys.email.rawValue)
        defaults.set(passwordTextField.text!, forKey: Keys.password.rawValue)
    }
}

func loadData() {
    // 8) updates the UI with the persisted data
    // Note that text property is optional so you can pass an optional string (no need to unwrap it)
    emailTextField.text = defaults.string(forKey: Keys.email.rawValue)
    passwordTextField.text = defaults.string(forKey: Keys.password.rawValue)
}
```

Comment: I see the problem, Thnx :))))))

Comment: @Nawaf check my last edit also to load the initial check box state before checking it

Comment: Im gonna apply it , and will let you know what gonna happen

Comment: @Nawaf I have added some comments to break down the code and explain the issues you were facing